# Android common webservice class from all activities

Tags: android, json, web-services, androidhttpclient

This is a simple doubt of me.

I had a android application with 10 activities. There is some web connection from each activities. So each and every activity I wrote  a ASYNC Task for connecting to web service.

Instead of that is there is any method for a common class which handle the webservice and return the data available ?

Something like this ( rough )

My Activity ->   Create a JSON for sending to server -> Call the WebserviceClass -> Send those JSON to that webservice Class -> Webservice will read the JSON -> Send to Server -> Return the status / result ( JSON) to "My Activity" -> Parse the JSON and so on ....

By this I can control all the webservice functionality with a single class

I am very new to android app development and please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE

Answer (score 1):

Google just released a new networking library called [Volley](https://developers.google.com/live/shows/474338138) made for just that! I think you will find it suitable to your needs (except if you want to download very big files, then use the `DownloadManager`)

You can find the GIT clone url [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/) to get the project

Look at [this](http://ogrelab.ikratko.com/android-volley-examples-samples-and-demos/) link for examples on how to use it

Comment: Hi @ramesh I haven't used it yet, just saw it on Google IO. There are a bunch of examples out there. I edited my answer with a example link

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing only rest, in my opinion you could use http://square.github.io/retrofit/ which is really easy to use.

Also Volley as suggested by Neil is good, but a bit more complicated to use for your use case and mostly undocumented. You can find an example application they released here https://github.com/evancharlton/folly